# Protect a cell for everyone except for function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, protected

I am new to the world of apps script and I would like to know if is it possible to protect a cell for everyone(they can't change the value directly) but can be changed by a function that will be called by everyone ?
Thanks

edit: the user can't change direclty the cell but he has a button with a script which shloud be able to change the value of the protect cell but currently if I put the cell in "protect sheets and range" the script doesn't work

Comment: Please elaborate to give more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible.

***First Option***

Use the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) which would [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) the owner of the document.

[Here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script) is an example how to incorporate a service account in Apps Script.

> Make sure that you give to the service account the necessary scopes
>   and enable domain-wide delegation.

***Second option***

Deploy your script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) and execute it as [you](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions)

***Third Option***

Use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) - this will run on your behalf after you authorize it. You can e.g. set-up an installable onEdit trigger that will fire the script function if a certain cell (e.g. "A20") is edited by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that when the user start the script, it should be started like if it was the owner of the sheet who start this? There is not a simpler way without use SSO ?

Comment: Another possibility would be to create a Web App that is executed as a the script owner, see here for more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions

Comment: I have a function which increment a unique id stocked in script properties and I put this id in a cell that i would like to be protected for user so i think I can't externalize this function

Comment: There is also a worakaround: Use an installable trigger - this will run on your behalf after you authorize it. You can e.g. set-up an installable onEdit trigger that will fire the script function if a certain cell (e.g. "A20") is edited by the user. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: I will update my answer with all three possibilities - in case somebody else is interested in a solution.